# Maven error : Could not calculate build plan

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am getting the following errors and i do not know why. I have set up my project on multiple environments and Ive never had any issue but recently i have added the project to an environment running Windows 8 with everything set up correctly (e.g. Maven... ) and i seem to be getting this issue

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)
    - CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read 
     artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.5.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-
     plugin:pom:2.5.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Address family not supported by protocol family: connect
    - CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read 
     artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.5.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.5.1 
     from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. 
     Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.5.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Address family not supported 
     by protocol family: connect
```

and

```
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
```

I have looked at this online and have tried numerous different things listed below to try and resolve this issue but none of them seem to work. Just to note i am not using any proxies

- Delete .m2 repository, Maven -> Update Project...
- Delete all `.lastUpdated` files, Maven -> Update Project...
- Tried selecting "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases" when updating project

Does anyone have any other ideas on what i could try?

Comment: First try to build your project on command line and not within Eclipse....Apart from that. This ` Address family not supported...` looks like a network/firewall issue...

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse, go to Windows > Preferences > Maven > User Settings

In User Settings, fill in the field with the path to `settings.xml` > `%M2_HOME%\conf` (or the correct path).

Comment: Maven docs might help determine what the path to `settings.xml` is: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Quick_Overview

Comment: After configuring settings.xml file in IDE from Maven path, error is fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like that your project doesn't install the dependency needed.
Therefore you need to install it yourself.

Download both jar and pom files from the Maven Repository and installing it using the command (better than copying to the folder directly)

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DpomFile=<path-to-pomfile>
```

and also be sure that you have installed all the necessary repository for the project and cross verify in the   `.m2/repository`     folder with the jar files

Comment: even you can try to clean the .m2/repository/ folder manually using rm -rf and then rebuild the project. Hope this works for you. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error while setting up my project on new VM:

"CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.5.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.5.1 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.5.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out..."

**Cause and Fix for this in my case :**
I have apache-maven-3.2.5 installed on the system but found that
settings.xml file is missing in .M2 folder under my user name ( **C:\Users\MyUserName.m2**) hence above error on building the project

**Steps to fix:**

*Step 1:* Copy settings.xml from **C:\Users\Public.m2** to .m2 folder under my username on the VM ( **C:\Users\MyUserName.m2**)

*Step2:* Using CMD  run  a clean install after navigating to the project to see if issue is fixed and project builds without error
like this :
*C:\Selenium_Test_SetupB\WebUatDemo>mvn clean install*